# passing parameters to resource factory in angularjs from the controller not working

Tags: html, angularjs, web-services, rest, twitter-bootstrap-3

passing parameters to $resource in angularjs.

I have a  search button in the UI upon clicking which I want to pass the input parameter to the $resource which would call the REST service in the backend.

when I pass a string value in the .query it works perfectly fine, but the @issueinput is not getting resolved to the input value.

this is the app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router', 'ngResource']);

myApp.factory('SearchService',function($resource){
    return $resource("http://localhost:8081/support/api/search/:issuename");
});
```

this is the controller

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('searchCtrl',['$scope', '$window','SearchService', function($scope, $window, SearchService){

     $scope.data={};

    $scope.search = function(issueinput){    
     SearchService.query({issuename:'@issueinput'},function(response){
            $scope.data.issues = response; 
         });
    };
  }  
  ]);
```

this is the UI html

```
<html>
<div id="searchpage">
     <label>Search</label> :<input data-ng-model="issueinput"></input> {{issueinput}}  
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <button data-ng-click="search(issueinput)">Search</button>
     <br/>
     <br/>
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="s in data.issues">{{s.issueName}} : {{s.issueDescription}}</li>
</ul>


</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by making the following changes

controller

```
$scope.search = function(){  
SearchService.get({issuename: $scope.issueinput},function(response){
$scope.data.issues = response; 
});
```

$resource in app.js

```
myApp.factory('SearchService',['$resource',function($resource){
    return $resource("http://localhost:8081/support/api/issue/:issuename",{},
       {
        get:{
             method: 'GET',
             isArray:true}}
    );
}]);
```

Comment: big help, was about pulling my hair out  and found this post. what did it for me was adding the parameter on this line    SearchService.get({issuename: $scope.issueinput},function(response){